# Is the term "Hobbit Village" ever used canonically by Tolkien?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, j-r-r-tolkien, hobbits

In November 6th, 2023's New York Times Crossword Puzzle, there was a theme answer of "HOBBIT VILLAGE" for the clue "Home for Tolkien's Bilbo and Frodo". (Spoiler for the full puzzle):

> [image: NY Times crossword puzzle]

[Many crossword blogs](https://rexwordpuzzle.blogspot.com/2023/11/newly-weaned-piglets-mon-11-6-23-amazon.html) expressed extreme dissatisfaction with that answer.

> And HOBBIT ... VILLAGE? When I search ["Hobbit Village"] I just get movie sets in New Zealand. Do you mean The Shire? I only know The Shire.

This is followed by extensive debate in the comments whether HOBBIT VILLAGE is a thing or not.

Does Tolkien ever refer to places in the Shire (or another village) as a Hobbit Village, or the concept of Hobbit Villages as a specific canonical thing?

Comment: *Just then all the others came round the corner of the road from the village. They were on ponies, and each pony was slung about with all kinds of baggages, packages, parcels, and paraphernalia. There was a very small pony, apparently for Bilbo.* ~ The Hobbit

Comment: I guess I'm not upset at all about that clue and answer. I would not have expected that the answer was a direct Tolkien quote at all.

Comment: The problem is, it's the people who are complaining who are showing their lack of knowledge. The Shire is like an English shire, but larger even than old Yorkshire—over 100 miles across in any direction, perhaps 18,000 square miles. Saying that hobbits don't live in villages, but rather the Shire, is like saying that someone does not live in Coventry, but rather the Midlands.

Comment: What is the clue for 28 Across?

Comment: I'm not sure that I even understand the issue. The place where I live is not called "Massachusetts city" anywhere, but if you asked me if I live in a Massachusetts city, I'd say "Yes."  If the question asked for a proper name there'd be an issue, but this seems perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @MarkOlson entries in crossword puzzles must be recognizable things. So SEA WORLD is ok, but ORANGE BOAT would not be. You can't just string any adjective with any noun.

Comment: I suppose JRRT himself was born in BOER CITY, then, not Bloemfontein as I thought.

Comment: Also, before moving with Bilbo to HOBBIT VILLAGE, Frodo lived in HOBBIT VILLAGE.  Then, during the events of LotR, he together with his gardener Sam and their friend Merry from HOBBIT VILLAGE had to pretend moving to HOBBIT VILLAGE to avert suspicion that he needs to go from the HOBBIT COUNTRY on a quest, all the way to ELVEN bloody TOWN.

Comment: @Adamant Crossword people are not arguing about whether hobbits live in villages, but whether HOBBIT VILLAGE is a legitimate phrase. There's a rule against using so-called "green paint" in puzzles. Patrick Berry, an all-time great constructor, explains: *A constructor will cobble together an entry such as GREEN PAINT and justify it by saying, "Well, I can clue it as {Wall coating at Fenway Park}—that's painted green. And it gets a million Google hits, so it must be legit." The trouble is, GREEN PAINT simply isn't a phrase...*

Comment: *...Not just because it isn't in the dictionary—plenty of good entries aren't found in the dictionary, such as X-RAY VISION and YOU MAKE ME SICK. But you can imagine those phrases as entries in hypothetical reference works—a glossary of superhero powers for X-RAY VISION, and a giant compendium of insults for YOU MAKE ME SICK. It's a lot harder to conjure up a hypothetical reference work that would bother to list GREEN PAINT.*

Comment: Per [one Reddit commenter](https://www.reddit.com/r/crossword/comments/17ooapa/nyt_monday_11062023_discussion/k842j9p/): "It’s like saying Elrond lives in ELFCASTLE, Treebeard is from ENTFOREST and Aragorn is from MANLAND."

Comment: @JohnKugelman - It's like saying that Elrond lived in an elven dwelling, that Treebeard was from an Ent forest, and Aragorn was from a human land. All true.

Comment: All true, but none of those would be acceptable crossword entries. That's the distinction I'm making.

Comment: @PM2Ring: The clue, apparently, was "Home for Tolkien's Bilbo and Frodo".

Comment: @V2Blast Unfortunately, giving a crossword clue that sounds specific but has a generic answer is all too common.

Answer (score 28):

### Tolkien frequently refers to Hobbit settlements as "villages", but the phrase "Hobbit Village" has never been used by Tolkien

The first usage would be *The Hobbit*, referring to Hobbiton

> Just then all the others came round the corner of the road from the village. They were on ponies, and each pony was slung about with all kinds of baggages, packages, parcels, and paraphernalia. There was a very small pony, apparently for Bilbo.
> <sub>*The Hobbit* - Chapter 2 - "Roast Mutton"</sub>

In the Lord of the Rings, we get some additional usages, explicitly confirming that Hobbiton, Tuckborough, Woodhall, Bucklebury, Frogmorton, Bywater, and Gamwich are all villages, but that Michel Delving is not and is instead a "township".

> Indeed, even in the hilly regions and the older villages, such as Hobbiton or Tuckborough, or in the chief township of the Shire, Michel Delving on the White Downs, there were now many houses of wood, brick, or stone.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Prologue, 1 - "Concerning Hobbits"</sub>

> Nearer at hand a few lights twinkled in the village of Woodhall.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Book I, Chapter 3 - "Three is Company"</sub>

> Its chief village was Bucklebury, clustering in the banks and slopes behind Brandy Hall.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Book I, Chapter 5 - "A Conspiracy Unmasked"</sub>

> As evening fell they were drawing near to Frogmorton, a village right on the Road, about twenty-two miles from the Bridge.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Book VI, Chapter 8 - "The Scourging of the Shire"</sub>

> But in the village of Bywater all the houses and holes were shut, and no one greeted them.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Book VI, Chapter 8 - "The Scourging of the Shire"</sub>

> According to family tradition, set out in the Red Book, the surname *Galbasi*, or in reduced form *Galpsi*, came from the village of *Galabas*, popularly supposed to be derived from *galab-* ‘game’ and an old element *bas-*, more or less equivalent to our wick, wich. *Gamwich* (pronounced *Gammidge*) seemed therefore a very fair rendering.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Appendix F, II - "On Translation"</sub>

While not part of the shire, it should perhaps be noted that Hobbit settlements near the Anduin were also referred to as villages, as were the human/hobbit settlements in Bree-land

> “I wish you would not always speak so confidently without knowledge,” I said sharply. “These villagers have lived in the Shire some fourteen hundred years, and they have learned many things in the time.
> <sub>*Unfinished Tales* - "The Quest for Erebor"</sub>

> Bree was the chief village of the Bree-land, a small inhabited region, like an island in the empty lands round about. Besides Bree itself, there was Staddle on the other side of the hill, Combe in a deep valley a little further eastward, and Archet on the edge of the Chetwood. Lying round Bree-hill and the villages was a small country of fields and tamed woodland only a few miles broad.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings* - Book I, Chapter 9 - "At the Sign of the Prancing Pony"</sub>

Looking at some lesser known Tolkien writings, we can see a few other Hobbit settlements referred to as villages: Berendon, Overhill, Budgeford, Whitwell, Hardbottle, and Waymeet.

> *Breredon* (Briar Hill) was a little village on rising ground behind the hythe, in the narrow tongue between the end of the High Hay and the Brandywine.
> <sub>*The Adventures of Tom Bombadil* - "Preface"</sub>

> In his notes for the Dutch translator Tolkien said of Overhill: ‘plainly the village received its name since it was over or beyond The Hill from Hobbiton’.
> <sub>*The Lord of the Rings: A Reader's Companion* - Book I, Chapter 2</sub>

> Budgeford: Village by a ford over the Shire-water in Bridgefields (chief dwelling of the Bolgers)
>
> Whitwell: Village on the Downs near Tuckborough, home of Peregrin
>
> Hardbottle: Village in the Southfarthing
>
> <sub>Tolkien's unfinished LotR index, quoted in *The Lord of the Rings: A Reader's Companion* in Book I Chapter 5, Book V Chapter 1, and Book VI Chapter 9</sub>

> Waymeet: In the map [printed as] *Waymoot* in the text modernized as *Way-meet*, a village at the meeting of three ways. Translate by sense, as convenient.
> <sub>Nomenclature of the Lord of the Rings</sub>

However, in none of Tolkien's known writings does the phrase "hobbit village" appear.